# Reference for Spanish UI

Tags: gui-design, language

Is there a good reference for UI terms in spanish? Terms like username, password, login/logout, etc... aren't direct translations.

I'm looking for a guideline to translate these labels.

**Update**
I've started a running list of common UI terms with spanish translations.

Contribute: http://github.com/abenjamin765/spanish-ui

View: http://abenjamin765.github.io/spanish-ui

Comment: Hire a Spanish copywriter / translator? Anything other than that is going to be clunky and obviously auto-translated.

Comment: Is there not a standard translation for most UI components that could be documented?

Comment: I agree with @JonW - You need to hire someone to provide you with the cultural translation as opposed as word-for-word machine translation. Many languages (I don't know if Spanish is one of them) also change words and phrases depending on their context: the translation for a 'log in' button in the menu bar may be different to a 'log in' link in a body of text and different again for a button in a side panel.

Comment: This sounds like the logical thing to do...
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29018/spanish-ux-keywords-cheat-sheet?rq=1

Comment: Not having spanish available doesn't seem logical at all... A cheat-sheet however, is exactly what i'm looking for. 

I'm certain OK, Cancel, Login, Username, etc... have been translated to Spanish. Seems like a waste to bring in a translator for 10 - 20 labels.

Comment: But I would assume that, because you are requiring Spanish labels, you are doing a Spanish version of whatever app / site / product you are building. You can't just have Spanish translated buttons but all the content in English. If you have a target-audience of Spanish speakers then you need to internationalise the app to that audience properly.

Comment: @AaronBenjamin translators are essential. There is no magic cheat-sheet. Just like UX, language is heavily context-based. You need a human in the loop.

Comment: Translators are being utilized to write the product content. For the UI mock-ups, it'd be nice to plug and play labels that make sense the same way we utilize placeholder content and filler images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't find any guidelines (which I didn't) and the labels you need are widely used, you can take big sites as Google, Facebook, Twitter, Youtube as an example, **just search for the Spanish version of this sites**, they have neutral Spanish translations.

I'm a native Spanish speaker so I can tell you some of the most used:

- User: Usuario / Nombre de Usuario
- Password: Contraseña
- Sign up: Crear cuenta / Registrarte
- Log in: Ingresar / Acceder (acceder is the Google's choice, but less
  common).
- Cancel: Cancelar
- OK: OK
- Submit: Here the "convention" is to name the button with the actions that it performs, for example, "Post/send your question", "Create account" =
  "Crear cuenta",etc
  If you want some generic words for submit: Confirmar (confirm) /
  Enviar (Send).
- Exit: Salir
- Log out: Cerrar sesión / Salir
- Help: Ayuda
- Name: Nombre
- LastName: Apellido
- Telephone: Teléfono
- Cellphone: it depends on the country but a neutral could be "Teléfono móvil" (for e.g. in Argentina *Celular* would sound much more natural).
- Day/Month/Year: Día/Mes/Año
- Settings: Configuración

Comment: +1 nice list. One comment on "Log in=Acceder" : even though it's correct, it's less common because *acceder* in Spanish hast 2 meanings: *to get in* and *to agree*. btw, are you from Argentina?

Comment: @Devin  I agree with the comment about "Acceder", that's why I added it along with the Google + being less common clarification. I don't really know if 'acceder' has the 'agree' meaning in the other Spanish speaking countries, I'm counting on Google i18n for that :P. And yes, I'm from CABA, Argentina.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! If you want to tack on to the new resource I'm putting together, the repo is located at http://github.com/abenjamin765/spanish-ui. If there is anything out there, it's not easy to find. Here's to solving that problem!

Comment: How to say "Finish" for a button which completed a wizard?

Comment: @Devin the words "Acceso" and "Registro" have no other meanings in UI.

Comment: @roetnig, the specifically mentioned word was "Acceder", and I explained its 2 meanings. "Acceso" has only one meaning, as you said. About "Registro", I didn't say anything, so not sure what do you mean

Comment: @Devin, I know, I'm just giving alternatives without double meaning.

Comment: Log in = Iniciar Sesión (begin session), Log out, "Quitar Sesión"